# Search function only for a specific value of a key?

Tags: javascript, object, hashmap

So i have a map (key-value Object called "infos") that looks like this :

```
  1: [1, "alfred", "mainstreet"]
  2: [2, "james" , "something"]
  3: [3, "chris" , "bla"]
```

Now i want to ONLY search for the 2nd. row, and then give back all the values of the key. Means i can only search for "alfred", "james" or "chris".

So if i would search for : "bla" in my keyboard input, NOTHING should show up.

```
infos = (MySearchedText) ? infos.filter(matchesText) : infos;

var regExp = new RegExp(MySearchedText, "i");
var matchesText = function(value) {
    return regExp.test(value);
}
```

With these functions, it compares ALL values with the searched text. Means if i even type "bla" it shows the whole 3rd key.

Comment: `infos` is not a valid object

Comment: So, is that `infos` a object or an array?

Comment: Edited. Its an object with multiple values

Comment: If it's an object, `infos.filter` wouldn't work. Also, those numeric keys aren't valid syntax.

Comment: Well i got told it is an hash map object, i've never worked with that before so yea. I can't tell. Looks like an array to me too. However, it is working and i can search for all of the values. I just don't know how to only search for the second value

Comment: Can you post the actual contents of `info`? It's declaration? Is this some kind of school assignment?

Comment: No it's not, im just new to javascript and never worked with objects or arrays before. In debugging it says that its a Object. And its exactly looking like in the top with { } around

Comment: please add some examples for searching and the results as well.

Comment: if "MySearchedText" will be , for example "a", i would get the following keys : 1, 2, 3. Since the letter "a" is in all 3 keys. BUT it should only give me key 1 and 2. Since i only want to look for the 2nd value. James has an "a", michael has an "a", chris has not. With the function above it is looking at ALL values for each key and i dont want that

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe...

```
var arr = [
  [1, "alfred", "mainstreet"],
  [2, "james" , "something"],
  [3, "chris" , "bla"]
];

var search = function(name){

   return arr.filter(function(a){
      return a[1].indexOf(name) != -1
   })

}

search('alfred'); // an array with results
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the keys of the object and check the value at the given index for a wanted string.

```js
function getKeys(object, index, value) {
    return Object.keys(object).filter(function (k) {
        return object[k][index].indexOf(value) !== -1;
    });
}

var data = {  1: [1, "alfred", "mainstreet"], 2: [2, "james" , "something"], 3: [3, "chris" , "bla"] };

console.log(getKeys(data, 1, 'a'));
console.log(getKeys(data, 2, 'bla'));
```